# Howto use an existing source package (work in progress,some classes not compiled) in java into netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an ongoing project done in command line .I have almost 20 classes written .However, now I want to continue my work in Netbeans . It will be tedious to create files,copy and paste into netbeans. Is there any way to open the whole directory of my project as package in netbeans or any other way around the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new netbeans project of your app type (jar/war/...)

- Copy paste the source files in appropriate dir
- Add the required lib

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,Jigar.Actually  your help worked for compiled classes. As for sources I had to do this :  Project Window >Source Packages>(Right Click)>Properties>Sources>Add Folder>(now select the folder)>OK. Now, I have no problem with compiled and not compiled files.Thanks.